# slack rtm_connect is not returning the output

Tags: python, slack

When running slack bot fails with below error, where as at the same time api_calls api.test, auth.test seems working fine, any idea how this can be fixed ? Am i missing anything?

Error :

```
 No handlers could be found for logger "slackclient.client"
 Connection Failed
```

Code Snippet:

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
import os


slack_token = os.environ["SLACKBOT_LUMBERGH_TOKEN"]
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

if sc.rtm_connect():
    while sc.server.connected is True:
        print sc.rtm_read()
        time.sleep(1)
else:
    print "Connection Failed"
```

When I add

```
print slack_client.api_call("api.test")
print slack_client.api_call("auth.test")
```

Its returns the value. Am i missing anything here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the python and pip to latest, it worked smoothly after that.